# Resolving a dependency issue with a web app in Dart/Mojito

Tags: dart

I recently stumbled across Dart, and got pretty excited about it because it almost feels like that perfect language I've always been looking for. I work with PHP at my job (Yes, I know, ew gross) as a web developer and was excited to try and build a web app using the language. Figured it couldn't be too hard as that's what Dart was originally made for. Turns out it more difficult than I though, and I can't even get off the ground. I was hoping someone else could help point me in the right direction.

So, I really haven't done any real coding in this project at all. I literally downloaded the Dart SDK, used stagehand to create `web-simple` project, then I added a `bin/server.dart` file to the project. The code in that file was pretty much taken straight out of the online documentation for the mojito package:

```
import 'package:mojito/mojito.dart';

main() {
  var app = init();

  app.router
      ..addStaticAssetHandler('/static');

  app.start();
}
```

I added the dependency `mojito: "^0.6.6"` to the pubspec.yaml file as well of course. That's all I've done though, like I say, I haven't even managed to get off the ground yet.

When I run `server.dart` I get the following error:

```
'package:convert/src/percent/encoder.dart': malformed type: line 23 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'PercentEncoder'
```

I get the exact same error message if I try to build a server with the shelf_rest package instead of the mojito package.

A search of that error message doesn't bring up too much helpful info, though I found one forum where someone recommended adding `convert: ^2.0.1` to the dependencies. Apparently there was a change made in that package that causes incompatibility with other packages. I tried that suggestion but it doesn't seem to be resolving the issue.

I'm certain the issue is some sort of dependency issue, I'm probably using a mix of dependencies that I guess just aren't meshing right. If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated. I want to learn and start using Dart but obviously I'm not having such great luck with it...

Here's what the `pubspec.yaml` looks like in case it helps:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  shelf: ^0.6.0
  mojito: "^0.6.6"
  convert: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version of mojito was uploaded in [October 2016](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mojito#-versions-tab-) and it seems abandoned.  Since then, Dart has added Strong mode and begun transitioning to Dart 2.  This included significant changes to the type system and updates to SDK libraries.

Additionally, transformers have also been removed - any documentation you find referencing them is out of date.  And in this case, the dart2js script rewriter is for client side JavaScript, not servers.

If you're looking for Server libraries, I would recommend just starting with the latest version of [Shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf)

Comment: Really? That's too bad, it looked like it was the more feature-rich package of the two and would save a fair amount of work. But, at least now I know. Using shelf alone doesn't give any errors with some simple example code so I guess that takes care of that problem.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are other, more maintained packages out there - maybe ask on r/dartlang or the gitter chat https://gitter.im/dart-lang/sdk

Comment: As an update I think I've decided to give Aqueduct a try. Also found another framework called Angel that seems to be currently maintained as well, so far as I can tell. Just for any others who had the same question I did.